# How to execute tests after an event

Tags: javascript, node.js, continuous-integration, jestjs, discord.js

I want to test some functions that require a Discord.js Client to be "ready", but I don't find how to make Jest run my tests after an event. I tried moving the tests in a function like

```
client.on("ready", () => {
  test(...);
})
```

but when I run `npm test` it detects 0 tests.
I also tried to write the `client.on` function inside the tests but it doesn't detect the `expect` and passes without checking anything.

```
test("sample", () => {
  client.on("ready", () => {
    expect(...);
  })
})
```

I tried looking at the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/getting-started.html) but I didn't find anything.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a promise that resolves and the test waits for it

```
test("sample", async() => {
  const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
     client.on("ready", () => {
       resolve()
     })
  })
  await p
  expect(...);

})
```

Also have a look on how to [work with asynchronous code](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html) in tests

Answer (score 0):

By passing the `done` argument Jest will wait until `done()` is called.

```
test("sample", done => {
  client.on("ready", () => {
    expect(...);
    done();
  })
})
```